# I start off in TTY7, but end up in TTY2, how come?

Tags: gnome, login, suspend, login-screen, session

When I start my machine, I first see that I am in TTY1, and then the mouse appears and I am in TTY7. It's a little odd, but doesn't bother me too much. However, and I think that this only happens after a suspend, but I can't be fully sure of it, when I then suspend my machine and leave it for a while, when I come back, I realise that my session has in fact moved to TTY2, because if I go to TTY1, or any of the others (except for TTY7 which I am coming to), I just see the usual black with white text login prompt console screen. But if I then tell it to go to TTY2, I get the GUI locked screen, and if I type my password in it will unlock my session. However if I then try and navigate to TTY7 with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> I find the the bit that I drag up to get to the login screen is of a different locked screen image to the penguin one which I have set, and it's not even the default. It's this one:

[image]

And when I pull that up I find that it's a login screen, and not even a locked screen, so it's actually a different session which has not even been logged into. So this is very strange, and something which has started recently as well is that before I do a suspend (as it does not seem to occur afterwards, and after this strange user session move has occurred), I find that if I switch to any other TTY from TTY7, when I come back, the TTY7 session has locked. This may not be of relevance but I thought it worth mentioning as perhaps what ever is causing it is also causing this strange user session move. Whether it's a bug causing a bug, or whatever it is, I thought it worth mentioning.

So anyway, now that I have told you my bizarre story which only started happening recently and has never happened to me before, what do you think could be the cause? And is there any fix or this behaviour to get it not to jump around to different TTYs?

I am running Ubuntu Gnome 15.04, with Gnome Shell, and Gnome 3.16 (I didn't have these issues on Gnome 3.14, so it could be somehow related to something in Gnome 3.16). Also, when I had Unity, I never had anything like this, so I am sure that it is a Gnome issue.

**Information Update:**

I have checked again and it is definitely being caused, or at least only starting to occur, after a suspend.

Comment: Did you find any information about how to solve this issue? I have shut down and booted the notebook a few times but I'm landing to TTY2 and all my gnome settings (enabled extensions and tweaks) are lost :(

Comment: I was literally just about to ask this question: anon@nixbox:~$ who
anon     tty2         2016-11-04 12:37 (:0)

Comment: @ЕлинЙ.: Nope, I still haven't figured out how to fix this.